# integrate login of FOSUserBundle in FOSOAuthServer

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0, fosuserbundle, fosoauthserverbundle

I am tying to integrate `FOSUserBundle` with `FOSOAuthServerBundle` now when I fire the url

```
http://localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/login
```

I can see the `FOSUserBundle` form which prompts for username and password.

But what I want to implement is once the user logs in successfully I want to generate `Token` from `FOSOAuthServerBundle` so in a way I want to use `FOSUserBundle` existing form into `FOSOAuthServerBundle` so that after login I can generate `Auth Token and Id` and then seamlessly user can call Rest APIs.

Here is a snippet of `security.xml`:

```
oauth_authorize:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/auth
            form_login:
                 provider: fos_userbundle
                 check_path: /oauth/v2/auth/login_check
                 login_path: /oauth/v2/auth/login
            anonymous: true
```

so when a user visits `/oauth/v2/auth/login` they can prompt to enter user name and password from `FOSUserBundle`.

Comment: If someone know how to resolve this issue... It would be very helpful :/

Answer (score 0):

There's the answer here :
http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/04/securing-syfmony2-rest-service-wiith.html

It explains how to build an extended login form based on FOSOAuthServerBundle instead of FOSUserBundle.